# Simple Array Coordinate Display Matching

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, multidimensional-array

I am attempting to create an array which takes user input and breaks at 99 99 but the multidimensional array does not stop taking inputted values.  Another issue is getting the values to display on the grid down below in the visual representation.  If more clarification is needed, please let me know.

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

srand(time(0));

int organisms[22][22];
int rows,
    columns;
int input[22][22];
int *output = new int[];

//filling array

for(int i=0;i<22;i++)
{

    for(int j=0;j<22;j++)
    {
        organisms[i][j]=0;
    }
}


//column output

cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tColumn\n\n";
for(columns=1;columns<21;columns++)
{
    cout<<"\t"<<columns;
}
cout<<"\n\n\n";

//Row and data output

    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
    {

        cout<<"Row  "<<i+1<<"\t";

        for(int j=0;j<20;j++)
        {
            cout<<organisms[i][j]<<"\t";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
cout<<"\n\n\n";
cout<<"Enter each cell in first colony use row space column Enter format, 3 4, for example.\nEnter 99 99 to end entries.\n";

//input of values

cin.ignore(4);

int m=0;


do
{

    cin>>input[m][m];
    m++;

    if(input[m][m]!=99,99)
        break;

}while(m<20);



/*
while(input[m][m]!=99,99)
{
    cin>>input[m][m];
    m++;

}
 /*
for(int m=0;m<INT_MAX;m++)
{
    cin>>input[m][m];

    if(input[m][m]==99)
        break;
}
*/


//input array indexing






//output array

cout<<"\n\n\n";
cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tColumn\n\n";
for(columns=1;columns<21;columns++)
{
    cout<<"\t"<<columns;
}
cout<<"\n\n\n";

        for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
        {

        cout<<"Row  "<<i+1<<"\t";
        cout<<endl;

        for(int n=0;n<20;n++)
        {
            cout<<input[i][n]<<"\t";
        }

        cout<<endl;
}

cin.get();
cin.get();

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

const size_t size=20;

char table[size][size];

void table_clear(void){
    for(int v = 0; v<size; ++v)
        for(int h = 0; h<size; ++h)
            table[v][h]=' ';
}

void table_put(pair<int, int> p){
    int v = p.first;
    int h = p.second;
    table[v-1][h-1] = '*';//to zero origin
}

void table_disp(){
    cout << "   ";
    for(int i=0; i<size;++i){
        cout << setw(3) << i + 1;
    }
    cout << "\n" << endl;
    for(int i=0;i<size;++i){
        cout << setw(3) << left << i + 1;
        for(int j=0;j<size;++j){
            cout << setw(3) << right << table[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    vector<pair<int,int> > v;
    pair<int, int> end(99,99);
    pair<int, int> rc;

    cout << "Enter each cell in first colony use row space column Enter format, 3 4, for example.\n";
    cout << "Enter 99 99 to end entries." << endl;
    while(true){
        int row, column;
        cin >> row;
        cin >> column;
        rc = make_pair(row, column);
        if(rc == end)
            break;
        v.push_back(rc);
    }

    table_clear();
    for(vector<pair<int,int> >::const_iterator iter = v.begin();iter != v.end(); ++iter ) {
        table_put(*iter);
    }
    table_disp();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to do this without Vectors?  I'd prefer to keep it a regular array.

Comment: @KlineTel I think easy that vector replace to an array. But towards the vector is useful in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(input[m][m]!=99,99)
```

your input is an array of int, `99,99` is not an int. use valid int value, `5555` for example, or simple `99`

Comment: The cin.ignore(500) was getting in the way.  I changed it to cin.ignore(4).

Comment: Now the difficult part is getting these coordinates to show up on the second output.

Comment: what exactly is difficult?  ; p btw: nice naming convention, organisms, heh

Comment: I am not sure how to approach placing the inputs into their given coordinates on the second array output.  --And thanks, ha.  The cin.ignore is only so good for so many characters...

Comment: @KlineTel you can consider another question

Comment: --How can I use the values obtained within the input array to display on a grid below?  See above picture.

Comment: The memory addresses only display in the output.